# how to print data outside fetch function?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch function that not returns the data.

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/";
var testData = fetch(url, {
  method:'GET'
})
.then(function(resp){  
    return resp.json();
})
.then(function(data){
    return data;
});

console.log(testData); // here i want to print data
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is returning a `Promise<Response>`.You can't wait until promise finishes in the caller code. See more in this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440632/how-to-block-for-a-javascript-promise-and-return-the-resolved-result). You can read more on promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You can print the result in the last `then` call:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/";
fetch(url, {
  method:'GET'
})
.then(function(resp){  
    return resp.json();
})
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```